# How can i acess my parameters from the dynamic reconfigure server?

Tags: c++, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I already read the tutorials about the dynamic reconfiguration,
my problem now is that the tutorials use ros.spin() therefor as long as i dont change a value in the gui i dont get a callback and as a result my code just got stuck than.

I change the code now a bit to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 ros::init(argc, argv, "dynamic_tutorials");
  dynamic_reconfigure::Server<dynamic_tutorials::TutorialsConfig> server;
  dynamic_reconfigure::Server<dynamic_tutorials::TutorialsConfig>::CallbackType f;
  f = boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2);

 while(true)
{
  server.setCallback(f);
  ROS_INFO("Spinning node");
  ros::spinOnce();
 
}
 return 0;
}
```

well now i get the values each loop.
but the problem is that at each loop the gui gets updated this makes it now imposible in the gui to change any value in a textbox like strings. changing sliders/checkboxes is working fine.

as I think its a problem with the server.setCallback function I wana know if there is an other way to get my parameters.

EDIT:

```
void callback(dynamic_tutorials::TutorialsConfig &config, uint32_t level) {
  ROS_INFO("Reconfigure Request: %d %f %s %s %d", 
            config.int_param, config.double_param, 
            config.str_param.c_str(), 
            config.bool_param?"True":"False", 
            config.size);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65494/how-can-i-acess-my-parameters-from-the-dynamic-reconfigure-server-?/) by [Stiebi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4715/stiebi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-06-19**:
Could you post your callback code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why would you want to get a callback when nothing changes? Your dynamic reconfigure callback will be called:

- once, when your node is loaded, to pass the initial parameter settings
- after that only when something changes, e.g. through the GUI

I guess what you mean by "my code is stuck then" is that you put some other code into the callback that you want to have executed regularly (independent from whether a dynamic reconfigure setting changes). The solution is to simply put that code into your `while (true)` loop. And move the `setCallback()` call out of that loop, it should only be called once.

If you need to access the dynamic reconfigure config from your main code (you probably do), just save the config to a member variable in your callback and read that variable from your main loop.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The callback function won't work if nothing changes. But if you want to get the params, you can also use ros::param in your  code, the dynamic params can also be accessed on the param server with the same param name in dynamic_param server.
Hope this helps you

---

Originally posted by [Laura](https://answers.ros.org/users/86601/laura/) with karma: 35 on 2021-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1